# How to populate list<t> elements inside a class?

Tags: c#

I have a problem about populating `list<>` elements. I tried to set a value to first element of `list<>` object but it didn't work. Here is my two classes:

**CLASS**

```
        class hotel
        {
            public List<room> rooms = new List<room>();
        }
        class room
        {
            public string roomName;
        }
```

**Form1.cs**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string word = "example";
            hotel[] h = new hotel[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < h.Length; i++)
            {

                h[i] = new hotel();
                h[i].rooms[i].roomName = word;//It gives "Index out of range exception" error. 
            }
        }
```

Comment: `h[i].rooms.Add(new Room(){roomName="something"})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting an error because, while you have created a new `hotel`, you haven't added any `room`s to it. Your code would have to do something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < h.Length; i++)
{
    h[i] = new hotel();
    h[i].rooms.Add(new room { roomName = word });
}
```

If you want to add multiple rooms, you would either need to call `Add` multiple times or do so inside of an inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < h.Length; i++)
{
    h[i] = new hotel();
    // Add 10 rooms
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        h[i].rooms.Add(new room { roomName = word });
    }
}
```

Comment: that's the solution. i'll mark this as solution after this "you can accept in x minutes" rule.
if i want to add multiple rooms in a "hotel", what should i write?

Comment: @AloneInTheDark - You would have to create an inner loop (for however many rooms you wanted to add) and call the same `Add` method.

Comment: may you edit your question for a little example about this? thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You have not added a room to the hotel:

```
h[i] = new hotel();
var room = new room();
room.roomName = word;
h[i].rooms.Add(room);
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to have a shortcut method in your class:

```
public class Hotel
{
    public Hotel()
    {
        Rooms = new List<Room>();
    }

    public List<Room> Rooms { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Hotel WithName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Hotel AddRoom(string name)
    {
        Rooms.Add(new Room { Name = name });
        return this;
    }
}

public class Room
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Returning the `Hotel` object itself will allow method chaining on the same object to make the operations read fluently.

Demo:

```
var hotels = new List<Hotel>();

var hiltonHotel = new Hotel()
                      .WithName("Hilton")
                      .AddRoom("104")
                      .AddRoom("105");

hotels.Add(hiltonHotel);
```

Demo 2:

```
var hotelNames = new List<string> { "Hilton", "Sheraton", "Atlanta" };

var hotels = new List<Hotel>();

foreach(var hotelName in hotelNames)
{
    var hotel = new Hotel()
                    .WithName(hotelName);
    hotels.Add(hotel);
}
```

Demo 2 with LINQ:

```
var hotelNames = new List<string> { "Hilton", "Sheraton", "Atlanta" };
var hotels = hotelNames.Select(h => new Hotel().WithName(h)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, You need to add `room` to `hotel`

```
h[i].rooms.Add(new room {roomName = word});
```

Instead of

```
h[i].rooms[i].roomName = word;
```